# CPU utilization for given command in Linux

Tags: linux, profiling

For generic commands in Linux like htop, ping, who, scp etc.

how to know how much % of CPU is being used when they were executed?

are there any Linux tools which can give the stats for above commands!

Comment: The /proc directory has a stat file for each process with this information

Answer (score 0):

while **top** is running:

1. press **o** to open filter options
2. type COMMAND=your-script-to-monitor

for **htop**:

1. press **F4** to filter by command name
2. type in your command

From here, you can check the **CPU%** column

Answer (score 0):

You can try also this:

```
 ps -p <PID> %cpu
```